# ORACLE: creating a trigger that inserts data into another table

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

I'm still handling the very basics still, and in my database when there's an insert into "PRENOTAZIONE", the trigger I wrote should THEORETICALLY insert all the data I want into another table called FATTURAZIONE, but when I tested it I get the following error:

```
INSERT INTO PRENOTAZIONE(ID_RISTORANTE,ID_UTENTE,ID_ORDINAZIONE,ORA,DATA_PRENOTAZIONE)
VALUES (2,21,1,'12:00',CURRENT_DATE)
```

> Report error - ORA-01403: no data found ORA-06512: at
>   "VALERIO.TRIGGER1", line 16 ORA-04088: error during execution of
>   trigger 'VALERIO.TRIGGER1'

Here's my code, I hope you can help me figure out what am I doing wrong:

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
AFTER INSERT ON PRENOTAZIONE 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
dataEmissione DATE;
idRistorante NUMBER;
idProprietario NUMBER;
indirizzo VARCHAR2(20);
partitaIva NUMBER(38);
codiceFiscale VARCHAR(100);
idUtenteRegistrato NUMBER;
indirizzoUtente VARCHAR(100);
idMetodo NUMBER;
idListinoUtente NUMBER;
totaleFattura BINARY_DOUBLE;
BEGIN
 dataEmissione := :NEW.DATA_PRENOTAZIONE;
 idRistorante := :NEW.ID_RISTORANTE;
 SELECT PR.ID_PROPRIETARIO INTO idProprietario FROM PROPRIETARIO PR,RISTORANTI R
 WHERE PR.ID_PROPRIETARIO = R.PROPRIETARIO;
 SELECT R.INDIRIZZO INTO indirizzo FROM RISTORANTI R
 WHERE R.ID_RISTORANTE = :NEW.ID_RISTORANTE;
 SELECT R.PARTITA_IVA INTO partitaIva FROM RISTORANTI R 
 WHERE :NEW.ID_RISTORANTE = R.ID_RISTORANTE;
 SELECT UR.CODICE_FISCALE INTO codiceFiscale FROM UTENTE_REGISTRATO UR
 WHERE UR.ID_UTENTE = idProprietario;
 SELECT UR.ID_UTENTE INTO idUtenteRegistrato FROM UTENTE_REGISTRATO UR
 WHERE UR.ID_UTENTE = :NEW.ID_UTENTE;
 SELECT UR.RESIDENZA INTO indirizzoUtente FROM UTENTE_REGISTRATO UR
 WHERE UR.ID_UTENTE = idUtenteRegistrato;
 SELECT M.ID_METODO INTO idMetodo FROM METODI M, ORDINAZIONE O
 WHERE M.ID_METODO = O.ID_METODO AND O.ID_ORDINAZIONE = :NEW.ID_ORDINAZIONE;
 SELECT LU.ID_LISTINOUTENTI INTO idListinoUtente FROM LISTINO_UTENTI LU, ORDINAZIONE O
 WHERE LU.ID_LISTINOUTENTI = O.ID_LISTINOUTENTE AND O.ID_ORDINAZIONE = :NEW.ID_ORDINAZIONE;
 SELECT O.PREZZO_TOTALE INTO totaleFattura FROM ORDINAZIONE O
 WHERE O.ID_ORDINAZIONE = :NEW.ID_ORDINAZIONE;
 INSERT INTO FATTURAZIONE(DATA_EMISSIONE,ID_RISTORANTE,ID_PROPRIETARIO,INDIRIZZO,PARTITA_IVA,CODICE_FISCALE,ID_UTENTE_REGISTRATO,INDIRIZZO_UTENTE,ID_METODO_PAGAMENTO,ID_LISTINO_UTENTE,TOTALE_FATTURA)
 VALUES(dataEmissione,idRistorante,idProprietario,indirizzo,partitaIva,codiceFiscale,idUtenteRegistrato,indirizzoUtente,idMetodo,idListinoUtente,totaleFattura);
END;
```

EDIT: I tried modifying some of the code, but what I noticed is that if I don't use the :new, the code works, but if I try using it in any way, I will get the "no data" problem.

Comment: Looks like the first `select` didn't find any matching rows.

Comment: Can you limit your code to what is necessary ? I think that the error occurs at line 16, so I propose that you remove all other lines after first SELECT INTO because they polluate your question !

Comment: Okay I will do that in a few minutes, for now I noticed that I get the "no data found" problem only when I try accessing :new

Comment: handle exception properly and find which select return no data found and then fix it

Comment: *'I noticed that I get the "no data found" problem only when I try accessing `:new`'* The first `select` is giving `no_data_found` and does not refer to any value in the current triggering row. (That in itself seems odd but the logic is up to you.) By the way, you'll find that laying out code neatly will make program logic easier to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a procedure that has(almost) the same exact code I posted, but instead of using :new, I just use the trigger to call the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER FATTURA_TRIGGER 
BEFORE INSERT ON PRENOTAZIONE 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
PROCEDURE_FATTURA(:new.ID_RISTORANTE,:new.ID_UTENTE,:new.ID_ORDINAZIONE,:new.D_P);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

One (or more) `SELECT` statement in your trigger raised `NO_DATA_FOUND` error. There are a few options:

- use one of aggregate functions, such as `select max(pr.id_proprietario) into ...`
- use one exception handling unit for the whole trigger
- enclose each `SELECT` into its own `BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END` block and handle `NO_DATA_FOUND`

Basically, it depends on *what* you plan to do when such a thing happens.